# Is there any way to convert result from "nativescript-mediafilepicker" choose to byte [] for save it into Postgres database field bytea type?

Tags: nativescript

I am trying to convert an result from nativescript-mediafilepicker to bytea for store it into a field from a postgres database table. The result from the pick is:

I had test loadFromData, fromData methods from "image-source" for decode it too and nothing.

```
0: {
JS:   "type": "image",
JS:   "file": "/storage/emulated/0/Pictures/facebook/FB_IMG_15599124283098587.jpg",
JS:   "rawData": {}
JS: }
```

when i print "rawData" i get this:

```
JS: ==== object dump start ====
JS: constructor()
JS: <init>()
JS: describeContents()
JS: getOrientation()
JS: setOrientation()
JS: writeToParcel()
JS: equals()
JS: getBucketId()
JS: getBucketName()
JS: getDate()
JS: getId()
JS: getName()
JS: getPath()
JS: getSize()
JS: hashCode()
JS: isSelected()
JS: setBucketId()
JS: setBucketName()
JS: setDate()
JS: setId()
JS: setName()
JS: setPath()
JS: setSelected()
JS: setSize()
JS: clone()
JS: finalize()
JS: getClass()
JS: notify()
JS: notifyAll()
JS: toString()
JS: wait()
JS: ==== object dump end ====
JS: com.vincent.filepicker.filter.entity.ImageFile@3aee1ead
```

It is inserting into the database nice, but i know that is not working because when i tries to see the image from my program i can't, its a format damaged, and when i am doing from my webapp (JSP) it store it and shows like a charm.

Comment: Are you talking about postgres on backend server? Obviously you are not going to write the data from mobile app, you must be doing it via some API exposed by your backend team. You will probably send the file itself and it's the backend developer who has to read the file and write the data in whichever format he wants to postgres. You may use [nativescript-background-http](https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-background-http/) plugin to upload the file.

Comment: Ah ok, then from NodeJS (My backend) can i convert this to bytea?, you have right, i was trying convert from device.

Comment: how about converting the image to base64 encoded and storing the resulting string?